# React Native multiple options in Stack.Screen (params title + headerRight button)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a stack. The first screen is a list of items, and when you click on an item, a new screen is pushed in front where the title is the name of the item clicked. On this screen I also want a header button though, and I can't seem to get both working at the same time.

---

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Editor"
    component={PoetryEditor}
    options={
        ({route}) => ({title: route.params.poetryFormItem.formName})
    }
/>
```

^This works for setting the title

---

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Editor"
    component={PoetryEditor}
    options={
        {
            headerRight: () => (
                <Button onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()} title="Done"/>
            )
        }
    }
/>
```

^This works for adding the button

---

I have tried many combinations to try and get both of these "options" to work at the same time to no avail. I can't declare "options" twice because the second one will just cancel out the first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass an object to `options` or pass a callback which returns an object to use as options.

The first syntax means it's callback returns options with a `title` option, and the second one means it's options with `headerRight`. If you want both in the options, then you just put both in the options object:

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Editor"
  component={PoetryEditor}
  options={({ route }) => ({
    title: route.params.poetryFormItem.formName,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Button onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()} title="Done" />
    )
  })}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/